# Node.js - res.render won't update view on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using express and handlebars to build a web app. When I attempt to render a new template, however, the browser doesn't get updated at all. The console output contains the rendered html, but the page on screen stays the same. My code:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) { 
User.findByUsername(req.body.username, function(err, user) {
  if(err === null) {
    req.session.username = req.body.username;
    req.currentUser = user;
    console.log("rendering"); //prints
    res.render('x.handlebars', {currentUser : req.session.username});
  }
  else
    utils.sendErrResponse(res, 403, 'Username invalid');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.render` on server side will write the html content to the socket stream. It doesn't render to the screen.

The browser must read the response html and render it manually as,

```
responseText = //variable loaded its html content via ajax call
$("#someDivId").html(responseText)
```